# ASHWID component parts change after reboot

Tags: windows-runtime, uwp, windowsiot

Why do the ASHWID components for a) Processor, b) RAM, and c) BIOS change after rebooting my device?

This conflicts with the documentation, and means these parts cannot be used for generating a License Code, because every time the device is rebooted, the License Code is then invalid, and this is bad.

Device: Raspberry Pi 3 Model B v1.2

Windows IoT version 10.0.14936.1000

Example ASHWIDs:

01-00-A2-13-02-00-46-F5-03-00-7C-00-04-00-CF-CF-05-00-2C-55-07-00-EB-94-08-00-D9-33-09-00-C6-0F-01-00-A1-02-02-00-79-38-03-00-B7-71-04-00-19-9E-05-00-67-53-07-00-DD-CF-08-00-0B-72-09-00-46-06

01-00-5A-86-02-00-5A-B9-03-00-BC-71-04-00-23-9D-05-00-BD-90-07-00-92-1B-08-00-F1-41-09-00-77-70-01-00-41-CB-02-00-59-1D-03-00-40-3C-04-00-49-7B-05-00-2F-67-07-00-AC-EB-08-00-4C-CE-09-00-31-42

Comment: I tested it on version 14393 and encountered the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have not found a solution for the ASHWID problem, but a persistent unique ID for Licensing purposes can be obtained by sending a request from the device to the following link:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/networking/ipconfig
```

The returned JSON object can be parsed to get the MAC Address which can be used as a pseudo-DeviceId.

There is a code sample, not written by me, [here](http://embedded101.com/BruceEitman/entryid/676/windows-10-iot-core-getting-the-mac-address-from-raspberry-pi).